# "Unable to connect (8)" error with Mosquitto

Tags: ssl, openssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I have two servers with a very similar installation. One on Debian 8.7, the other on Debian 8.8.

On the first server, when I try to subscribe to a MQTT topic over SSL:

```
mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t test -p 8883 --cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/selfsigned.pem -d
```

I get this clear message which seems to come from OpenSSL (I already know the reason of the error, it is not the goal of my question) :

```
Client mosqsub/9647-CIEYY2T7 sending CONNECT
OpenSSL Error: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Error: Protocol error
```

On the other server, for the exact same command, I get only this obscure message without the OpenSSL explanation:

```
Unable to connect (8).
```

I have two questions:

- Why am I getting "Unable to connect (8)" on the second server?
- How can I make OpenSSL more verbose ?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, so probably off topic for Stackoverflow, it may be suitable for Super User, but better might be the mosquitto mailing list. Having said that I suspect mosquitto_sub is just printing what ever message openssl passes back to it.

Comment: So your top tags are mqtt and mosquitto and you come here only to ask to close the question ? That's a bit disappointing. I agree with your conclusion though, that's why my question is about openssl and not mosquitto client, but then where to go ?

Comment: I'm telling you that stackoverflow is the wrong venue for this question and pointed you at 2 places that are much more likely to get you an answer

Comment: *"Unable to connect (8)"* does not look like an OpenSSL error. If it was an OpenSSL error code, you could do `openssl errstr 0x8` and get a useful error message. Its probably coming from RabbitMQ or MQTT, and its probably due to a configuration error or firewall rule or something else breaking things. It looks like there is a lot of stuff on the web about the message: [mqtt "Unable to connect (8)"](https://www.google.com/search?q=mqtt+"Unable+to+connect+(8)"). A Mosquito bug report about it: [unable to load server key file mosquitto](https://answers.launchpad.net/mosquitto/+question/260828).

Comment: A mosquitto bug would make sense, but I'm using exaclty the same version both side (1.3.4-2), and if I replace the certificate with a valid one, everything works, so I don't think it would be some firewall problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here for the answer (where I've been told to go post the question on SO) :
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159177/how-to-make-openssl-errors-more-verbose-for-mqtt-client

And for the rules nazis trying to close this useful question/answer :

> if your question generally covers (...) software tools commonly used
>   by programmers (...) then you’re in the right place to ask your
>   question!

source : https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

And yes, mosquitto_sub and mosquitto_pub are tools commonly used by programmers, because if u are trying to setup a SSL MQTT connection directly with java code and bouncy castle without testing the exchange with simpler tools, you are probably doing it wrong.